# HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed ASP IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am trying to move a website from one server to another server but pointing to the same external database server. The error appeared was:

> HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

It was working in the previous server, and only in certain pages are working.

ASP is installed on the server role and tried edit the applicationHost.config to section name=”asp” overrideModeDefault=”Allow” but they didn't solve the issue. The application is the Default Web Site at the root directory in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Here's in web.config:

```
<system.webServer> 
  <defaultDocument> 
  <files> <clear /> 
   <add value="index.html" /> 
   <add value="Default.htm" /> 
   <add value="Default.asp" /> 
   <add value="index.htm" /> 
   <add value="iisstart.htm" /> 
   <add value="default.aspx" /> 
   <add value="index.php" /> 
  </files> 
  </defaultDocument> 
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" /> 
</system.webServer>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would temporarily remove the whole `<asp>` node from your web.config or even remove the whole web.config to see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf tried but still. here's in web.config:
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" />
    </system.webServer>

Comment: I would check `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` for any `<asp...` nodes. By default there should only be one `<cache>` node. Also check the Windows application eventlog.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf there's only one node: <cache diskTemplateCacheDirectory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\ASP Compiled Templates" />. What should i check in the event log?

Comment: Hmm, just any errors related to ASP in the application log. It all seems okay, have you tried a very simple classic asp page? Does that work on a different machine? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: not sure if this is related but in database manager  i also get an error "a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server."

Comment: @PeterHahndorf i've tried a simple asp page and it works. The index.asp also works. But when logging in, the error occurs. Yes, it works in previous server, just didn't work in current server. I'm using windows server 2012. Thank you for the quick reply and effort. Appreciate it.

Comment: So classic ASP in general works, but a specific page doesn't. You need to debug that page, turn on all error reporting. And if you use SQL-server, you need to fix the connection problem as well.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf so i enabled error reporting and found that it is because the parent path disabled by default. Enabled it and it works! Thank you thank youuuu :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error:

> HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

can have multiple cases, but usually it occurs when the classic asp engine can not start due to some (mis-)configuration settings on IIS.

Often the `<system.webServer><asp>` in the site's web.config causes this error if Feature Delegation has not been changed to `Read/Write` on the server level.

To investigate this further make sure you send the proper ASP error message to the brower `Send Errors To Browser` under `ASP-Debugging Properties`

If you have `IIS Management Scripts and Tools` installed (which you should to manage IIS with PowerShell) you can use:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'Default Web Site' -filter "system.webServer/asp" -name "scriptErrorSentToBrowser" -value "True"
```

If you still use IE disable `Show Friendly http error messages`

Also enable detailed error messages for the site:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/httpErrors" -name "errorMode" -value "Detailed"
```

you should see a more specific ASP error, if this case it was a

`ASP 0131 Disallowed Parent Path`

Adjust settings or code to fix the problem.

When done, change the error settings back to the more secure defaults unless you are on your own dev machine.

Comment: Good explanation and process, would just suggest maybe for the uninitiated pointing out the configuration commands are PowerShell CmdLets though as there is more then no way to change those settings.

Comment: The Feature Delegation (read/write) comment was a great tip!  solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

After moving an website from one server to another, I was able to resolve the error by restarting the Internet Information Services (IIS) via the command line. Just type `iisreset` in an administrative command prompt.